# Ejabberd api set_vcard database_failure

Tags: ejabberd

When I use the following command for the ejabberd API I get the following response;

```
curl -ik -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx' https://localhost:5280/api/set_vcard -d '{"user":"foo","host":"example.com","name":"FN","content":"foobar"}'

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Admin

"database_failure"
```

On the ejabberd log (level 5) I see this;

```
[info] (<0.607.0>) Accepted connection ::ffff:172.18.0.1:46622 -> ::ffff:172.18.0.3:5280
[debug] S: [{[<<"ws">>],ejabberd_http_ws},{[<<"bosh">>],mod_bosh},{[<<"oauth">>],ejabberd_oauth},{[<<"api">>],mod_http_api},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin}]
[debug] ({tlssock,#Port<0.18819>,#Ref<0.650175335.3240493057.203147>}) http query: 'POST' <<"/api/set_vcard">>
[debug] client data: <<"{\"user\":\"foo\",\"host\":\"example.com\",\"contents\":[\"FN:foobar\"]}">>
[debug] [<<"api">>,<<"set_vcard">>] matches [<<"api">>]
[info] API call set_vcard [{<<"user">>,<<"foo">>},{<<"host">>,<<"example.com">>},{<<"contents">>,[<<"FN:foobar">>]}] from ::ffff:172.18.0.1:46622
[debug] Command 'set_vcard' execution allowed by rule 'api service' (CallerInfo=#{caller_module => mod_http_api,caller_server => <<"example.com">>,ip => {0,0,0,0,0,65535,44050,1},oauth_scope => [<<"ejabberd:api-service">>],usr => {<<"admin">>,<<"example.com">>,<<>>}})
[debug] Executing command mod_admin_extra:set_vcard with Args=[<<"foo">>,<<"example.com">>,<<>>,<<>>,[<<"FN:foobar">>]]
```

It is using MySQL as a database (working fine for everything else) however when I watch the database general query log I don't see my API request trigger any queries. I see all the other normal ejabberd queries so there isn't a problem with the db connection and as mentioned earlier everything else works.

```
$ ejabberdctl status
The node ejabberd@e87da11aa894 is started with status: started
ejabberd 18.4.0 is running in that node
```

Does anyone have any clues they can throw my way? I've ran out of leads on what could be the issue.

!!! EDIT !!!

Work around

As mentioned in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2629 other people have experienced this issue. Changing config to disable the cache and clearing the vcard table in the database seems to be a work around;

SQL:

```
DELETE FROM vcard;
```

Config:

```
...
mod_vcard:
  search: false
  use_cache: false
...
```

Comment: After creating an issue in github (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2629) it turns out that switching off cache gets around the issue.
mod_vcard:
  search: false
  use_cache: false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is fairly permissive in what it allows, however once it's in the database the record will fail to load.

For 'set_vcard', the 'name 'is the field name you wish to alter and the content is the contents of that field.

```
{
  "user": "catman",
  "host": "the.host",
  "name": "FN",
  "content": "Cat Man"
}
```

ejabberd also caches queries, so once you have a barfed record it'll return 'database_failed' even if you've corrected your api call or fixed it in the database by hand. Caching can be disabled under the modules configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Notice in your log that it says:

> [debug] client data: <<"{\"user\":\"foo\",\"host\":\"example.com\",\"contents\":[\"FN:foobar\"]}">>

How can it be that **contents** is **FN:foobar**? I installed 18.04, setup mysql storage, and running this query:

> $ curl -v -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:5280/api/set_vcard -d '{"user":"user1","host":"localhost","name":"FN","content":"mi nombre curllll"}'

The log says:

```
21:42:29.638 [info] (<0.487.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:58412 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
21:42:29.638 [debug] S: [{[<<"api">>],mod_http_api},{[<<"bosh">>],mod_bosh},{[<<"oauth">>],ejabberd_oauth},{[<<"presence">>],mod_webpresence},{[<<"register">>],mod_register_web},{[<<"rest">>],mod_rest},{[<<"ws">>],ejabberd_http_ws},{[<<"admin">>],ejabberd_web_admin}]
21:42:29.639 [debug] (#Port<0.18079>) http query: 'POST' <<"/api/set_vcard">>
21:42:29.639 [debug] client data: <<"{\"user\":\"user1\",\"host\":\"localhost\",\"name\":\"FN\",\"content\":\"mi nombre curllll\"}">>
21:42:29.639 [debug] [<<"api">>,<<"set_vcard">>] matches [<<"api">>]
21:42:29.639 [info] API call set_vcard [{<<"user">>,<<"user1">>},{<<"host">>,<<"localhost">>},{<<"name">>,<<"FN">>},{<<"content">>,<<"mi nombre curllll">>}] from 127.0.0.1:58412
21:42:29.640 [debug] Command 'set_vcard' execution allowed by rule 'test commands' (CallerInfo=#{caller_module => mod_http_api,ip => {127,0,0,1}})
21:42:29.640 [debug] Executing command mod_admin_extra:set_vcard with Args=[<<"user1">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"FN">>,<<"mi nombre curllll">>] 
21:42:29.640 [debug] SQL: "select vcard from vcard where username='user1' and 0=0"
21:42:29.642 [debug] SQL: "begin;"
21:42:29.642 [debug] SQL: "UPDATE vcard SET vcard='<vCard xmlns=''vcard-temp''><FN>mi nombre curllll</FN><N><FAMILY>mi familia11</FAMILY></N><NICKNAME>mi apodoooooooooooooooooooo11</NICKNAME><PHOTO><BINVAL>R0lGODlhDwAPAJECAP//AAAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAPAA8AAAIulB2Zx5IA4WIhWnnqvQFJDTyhE4khaG5Wqn4tp4ErFnMY+Sll9naUfGpkFL5DAQA7</BINVAL><TYPE>image/gif</TYPE></PHOTO></vCard>' WHERE username='user1'"
21:42:29.644 [debug] SQL: "UPDATE vcard_search SET username='user1', fn='mi nombre curllll', lfn='mi nombre curllll', family='mi familia11', lfamily='mi familia11', given='', lgiven='', middle='', lmiddle='', nickname='mi apodoooooooooooooooooooo11', lnickname='mi apodoooooooooooooooooooo11', bday='', lbday='', ctry='', lctry='', locality='', llocality='', email='', lemail='', orgname='', lorgname='', orgunit='', lorgunit='' WHERE lusername='user1'"
21:42:29.658 [debug] SQL: "commit;"
```